# How to make socket emit command as synchronous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In this code, the program get uptime details from Linux server by using Node.js.

```
socket.emit("getuptime",{host:"192.168.*.*"});
$("#result").html("loading....");
socket.on("getuptimeresult",function(data){
   console.log("result = "+data);
});
```

Here, the second line code should execute only first line code fully completed. I am not sure when exactly get the result from the node. So I want to get it immediately after socket emits the code. Are there any possibilities?

Comment: You shouldn't build something synchronous on your socket. If you provide more details about what you are trying to achieve we can provide you better ways. But you are asking a question about the way you selected and it doesn't seem a right one.

Comment: @Val Not even related.

Comment: @Val this is not related to that question

Comment: @Ahmet, i need to get uptime details from linux server. Based on this result  i will add some logic in the javascript code.

Comment: the callback on the the event will do the trick

Comment: Manu, how it is possible. can you tell me the trick

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
let data = {host:"192.168.*.*"};
socket.emit("getuptime", data);
console.log(data);
```

If you want to use the data right after emitting, that is how you can do it. Update your question, if you meant something else.

**Update:**

If you want the data in `getuptimeresult`, you have to emit the data with that event name & also to you have to register the callback for that event, before you could emit the data on that event. Like below:

```
socket.on('getuptimeresult', function(data) {console.log(data);});
socket.emit('getuptimeresult', {host:"192.168.*.*"});
```

**Update 2:**

Based on your updated code in question,
I guess, from client(browser), you call server with host name using `getuptime` event & getting the result in `getuptimeresult` event. If so,

Client/Browser:

```
socket.emit("getuptime",{host:"192.168.*.*"});
$("#result").html("loading....");
socket.on("getuptimeresult",function(data){
  var html = convertDataToHTML(data); // you have to change this function for your case.
  $("#result").html(html);
});
```

Server:

```
socket.on("getuptime",function(data){
  var detail = getUptimeDetailsForHost(data); // you have to change this function for your case.
  socket.emit('getuptimeresult', details);
});
```

PS:

If you are using socket.io, no need for `getuptimeresult` event & you can use a callback. Ex:

Client/Browser:

```
$("#result").html("loading....");
socket.emit("getuptime", {host:"192.168.*.*"}, function(data){
  var html = convertDataToHTML(data); // you have to change this function for your case.
  $("#result").html(html);
});
```

Server:

```
socket.on("getuptime", function(data, callback){ // <-- notice callback parameter here.
  var detail = getUptimeDetailsForHost(data); // you have to change this function for your case.
  callback(details);
});
```

Comment: Sorry. result is printing host only. But it should print result from "getuptime"

Comment: Both code is on server. I can get the result throw this way. But actualy what i want is it should work synchronous via. But your code works as asynchronous via.

Comment: What do you mean by `synchronous`? Want to use the data outside of the callback? What is the use case of doing `synchronous` way?

Comment: It means the code execute orderly. suppose if i write any code (ex: alert("hello") ) between this code, it should execute as orderly.

Comment: @selvan that will never happen, for the simple fact that the browser will not block between sending a message and receiving a response.

Comment: @explorer, I just referred in books, it tells synchronous connection won't work in socket based connection... so I want to change the code ...